# When either $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$, or $ \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ do not exists, how to check whether given ODE is exact or not

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For a given ODE, such as $$M(x,y) dx + N(x,y) dy = 0$$
>
> if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \not = \frac{\partial N}{\partial 
>  x}$, how can we determine whether the given ODE is exact or not ?
>   Moreover, how can we find $F(x,y)$ ?

To be clear, (I guess) we can always integrate $M$ wrt $x$, and then take the derivative of the resulting function wrt $y$, and look for a possible $g(y)$, where $g(y)$ is the intagration "constant" coming from the integration of $M$ wrt $x$, but my question is that is there any other methods ? Moreover, to check whether there exists a $g(y)$ satisfying the above conditions leads an integration, which might not be possible or easy all the time, so in such cases, what can we do ?

**Edit:**

I'm not talking about non-exact ODEs, I'm basically asking what to do when either $M$ or $N$ is not belong to $C^1$, as I have explain in the comments of the answer of @dezdichado.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no guaranteed method to solve an inexact differential equation. You need to understand that if the exactness condition is not met, then the finding $F(x,y)$ by using antiderivatives of $M$ and $N$ may not be possible - because if it were, then the equation is exact in the first place.

A way to remedy the inexactness is to introduce an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$:
Write the equation in the form $$(\mu M)dx+(\mu N) dy = 0\quad (\dagger)$$
and then find $\mu$ such that above equation is exact. Existence of such $\mu$ is not always guaranteed; even if it is, you would end up having to solve a PDE for $\mu.$

In short, when the equation is not exact there is a little hope that it would be solved easily and explicitly.

Comment: But you are only considering $F(x,y) \in C^2$. I mean the ODE might be exact while also having $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \not = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ because we even do not know in priori that whether $M$ and  $N$ are in $C^1$.

Comment: By the way, my question is not about non-exact ODEs. I'm only considering the exact ODEs when $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \not = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$.

Comment: there is no exact ODE's with the partial derivative conditions violated.

Comment: Really ? Can't F(x,y) be exist and not belong to $C^2$, but it belongs to $C^1$ ? $F$ would have partial derivatives s.t $\partial F / \partial x = M$ and $\partial F / \partial y = N$, but since $F \not \in C^2$, you wouldn't have the equality of mixed partial derivatives, in general.

Comment: In this case, either $M$ or $N$ needs not being in the class $C^1$.

Comment: If $\partial M/\partial y \ne \partial N /\partial x$ then there are no such $F$ that satisfy $\nabla F = (M,N)$. You may find a $\mu$ such that there exists a $F_\mu$ where $\nabla F_\mu = (\mu M, \mu N)$. However, that still doesn't make the original equation exact.

Comment: @Dylan For a scalar function, to have equal mixed second partial derivatives, the scalar funtion have to be continuously differentiable upto second order, so my whole point is that **there are scalar function which are not continuously differentiable upto second order.**

Comment: This is definitely something you should've addressed in the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Equations where

$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \ne \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} $$

are by definition, inexact. I think what you mean to be asking is, whether there always exists an integrating factor $\mu (x,y)$ such that

$$ \frac{\partial (\mu M)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial (\mu N)}{\partial x} $$

This is a complicated question that requires solving a PDE.

---

As for the method you've described, where one finds a scalar function $F(x,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = M$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = N$, by first integrating

$$ F(x,y) = \int M(x,y) dx + g(y) $$

and differentiating

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = N(x,y) = \int \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} dx + g'(y) $$

However, note that if you take the partial derivative w.r.t $x$ this becomes
$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x} $$

which relies on the assumption of an exact equation in the first place. If the equation isn't exact, this method fails, and what ends up happening is the expression

$$ N(x,y) - \int \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} dx $$

is no longer just a function of $y$

Comment: please see my comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659887/when-frac-partial-m-partial-y-not-frac-partial-n-partial-x-how-t/2659943?noredirect=1#comment5497201_2659943

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $F(x,y)\in C^2$. Do you mean $\Bbb C$ as in complex-valued function? Whether or not functions are complex is not relevant here.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html

Comment: You shouldn't asssume everyone understands your notation without explaining it. As it is now, your question lacks a lot of context. [Here's a guide on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: This is not my notation, this is the general notation.

Comment: Sure, but my point still stands. It doesn't hurt to explain from the beginning.

Comment: Dylan, with that logic, I should also explain what does the symbol $\partial$ means.

Comment: If you think it helps, then by all means, do it. "partial derivative" and "twice differentiable" are not hard to say. The more context you give, the more accessible your question will get, and the more answers.